# openVPN route-nopull server vs client

Tags: linux, windows, vpn, openvpn

My client config has route-nopull directive and everything works fine. But if I push it (push "route-nopull") from the server (and delete from client) then my client (windows 10) cannot navigate on internet.
Here the working config (only subnet traffic through vpn):

server:

```
local a.b.c.d
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 45 120
persist-key
persist-tun
explicit-exit-notify
```

client.ovpn

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote a.b.c.d 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
route-nopull
```

Comment: You should probably include your configs.

Comment: server and client config added. I have two clients one linux and the other windows 10